# Node JS API end point with querying SQLite with join

Tags: node.js, sqlite, rest

I've got two tables in SQLite :

```
CREATE TABLE sites (

    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE devices (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    siteId INTEGER, 
    name TEXT,
    active BOOLEAN,
    CONSTRAINT device_fk_siteId FOREIGN KEY (siteId)
        REFERENCES sites (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

I'm creating easy rest api endpoint in NodeJs to get all devices for site. How to do this in right way?  I want to have this result:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Site 1",
    "devices": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Device 1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Device 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I triyed, but I should do something diffrent?

```
  app.get("/sites/:siteId", async (req, res, next) => {
    let sql = `SELECT * FROM sites as s 
    JOIN devices as d 
    ON s.id = d.siteId
    WHERE s.id = ?`;

    const result = db.get(sql, req.params.siteId);
    res.json(result);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLite's [JSON1 extension](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) functions :

```
SELECT json_object(
         'id', s.id, 'name', s.name, 
          'devices', json_group_array(
            json_object('id', d.id, 'name', d.name)
          ) 
       ) result
FROM sites as s JOIN devices as d 
ON s.id = d.siteId
WHERE s.id = ?
GROUP BY s.id, s.name
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=db5b61ccf40ffebf1ac80bb812005ec3).

Comment: Thank you, and then I don't need do return data by: res.json(result) yes?

Comment: @gregs the query returns the json object that you need.

Comment: Thank you, so this solution will be ok?

```
    const sql = `SELECT json_object(
      'id', s.id, 'name', s.name, 
       'devices', json_group_array(
         json_object('id', d.id, 'name', d.name)
       ) 
    ) result
    FROM sites as s JOIN devices as d 
    ON s.id = d.siteId
    WHERE s.id = ?
    GROUP BY s.id, s.name`;

    const dbRes = await db.get(sql, req.params.siteId);

    if (dbRes) {
      const { result } = dbRes;
      res.send(result);
    } else {
      res.send("");
    }
```

Comment: @gregs I can't help you with the js code. My answer is about the sql code to retrieve the json object.